# graphing data in R ? bar or pie graph

Tags: r

hi im new to R and help to create a graph like this to my code
[image]

so i have to compare the process time for each of the following 3 read commands " read_csv , read.csv, read.table..  i added the time to 3 dif variables but not sure how to graph it so that
the type of the read is written in the X axis and the timming in Y axis .. i tried puting the results in a dataframe or matrix but im not getting the graph i want " like the one attached ..
below is my code " with out the ggplot()

```
library(tidyverse)
setwd("~/Downloads/IntroR/Data")

#read_csv
start.time <- Sys.time()


read_csv("StudyArea.csv", col_names = TRUE)

end.time <- Sys.time()

Read_csvTime = end.time - start.time

#read.csv
start.time <- Sys.time()


read.csv("StudyArea.csv")

end.time <- Sys.time()

Read.csvTime = end.time - start.time

#read.csv
start.time <- Sys.time()


read.table("StudyArea.csv" , header=TRUE, fill=TRUE,quote="", sep=",")

end.time <- Sys.time()

read.tableTime = end.time - start.time

print(paste("the time it took to read a file using read_csv is:", Read_csvTime , "Seconds"))

print(paste("the time it took to read a file using read.csv is:", Read.csvTime , "Seconds"))

print(paste("the time it took to read a file using read.table is:", read.tableTime , "Seconds"))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```r
library(tidyverse)
# 1. Create example data
Read_csvTime   <- 2.7
Read.csvTime   <- 2.3
read.tableTime <- 2.1

plot_data <- tibble(
    func  = c("readcsv", "read", "Table read"),
    times = c(Read_csvTime, Read.csvTime, read.tableTime)
)

# 2. Plot data
plot_data %>% 
  
  # Change order
  mutate(func = as_factor(func) %>% fct_reorder(-times)) %>% 
  
  ggplot(aes(x = func, y = times)) +
  geom_col()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Maybe this helps also. An additional solution to jwarz solution.

```
library(tidyverse)

# construct dataframe
Read_csvTime   <- 2.7
Read.csvTime   <- 2.3
read.tableTime <- 2.1
df <- as.data.frame(cbind(Read_csvTime, Read.csvTime, read.tableTime))

# long format for ggplot
df_long <- df %>%
    pivot_longer(cols = Read_csvTime:read.tableTime,
names_to = "func",
values_to = "times")

# ggplot
figure1 <- ggplot(df_long, aes(x = reorder(func, -times), y = times)) + # order bars in desc 
    geom_bar(stat = "identity", fill="seagreen3") +
    labs(title = "Process control",
         subtitle = "(Time)",
         x = "times",
         y = "func") + 
    geom_text(
        aes(label=times),
        nudge_x=0,
        nudge_y=0.2) +
    scale_y_continuous(
        limits = c(0, 5),
        expand = expansion()
    ) 
# figure with theme
figure1 + theme_minimal()
```